# Using MetaMask with React and Truffle

Tags: web3js, metamask, truffle-contract

I currently have my app set up with testrpc + truffle-contract and I'm trying to set the current provider to Rinkeby (or whatever testnet I'm on in MetaMask). However, when I run the following code it spits an error. I'm calling `initWeb3` in my componentWillMount

```
initWeb3() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

        TicketSaleContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

    } else {
        console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')

        window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        TicketSaleContract.defaults({
            from: '0x...',
            gas: 4712388,
            gasPrice: 100000000000
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the error...?

Comment: You can start a new project with truffle and react that is a good starting point. What you show in the code doesn't look like a good pattern. Do truffle unbox react and replace the contract that comes with that with your own.